# Using std algorithm library for unique equivalence with respect to binary relation

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std

I have binary relation on some type `T` induced by a function `equivalent`:

```
bool equivalent(T const& a, T const& b); // returns true if a and b are equivalent
```

It has the properties that

```
equivalent(a, a) == true
```

and

```
equivalent(a, b) == equivalent(b, a)
```

for all `a`, `b`.

For a given collection of elements of type `T`, I want to remove all but the first occurrence of each equivalence class. I have come up with the following Code but was wandering:

**Is there is a solution without an explicit loop?**

```
std::vector<T> filter_all_but_one_for_each_set_of_equivalent_T(std::vector<T> const& ts) {
  std::vector<T> result;
  for (auto iter = ts.begin(); iter != ts.end(); ++iter) {
     auto const& elem = *iter;
     bool has_equivalent_element_at_earlier_position = std::any_of(
        ts.begin(),
        iter,
        &equivalent
     );
     if (not has_equivalent_element_at_earlier_position) {
        result.push_back(routing_pin);
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

## Update

As far as I understand `std::unique` won't do because my type `T` is not sortable. And because I only have C++11 in my case, but I would be interested in other options too for education.

Comment: Hmm sounds like a job for std::unique, edit: c++11 tag, yeah that won't help you.

Comment: [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) - however, this would make *all* elements unique, not only a specific one...

Comment: Making *all* elements unique is what I want. They are not sortable, though.

Comment: True, but more importantly: "Eliminates all but the first element from every **consecutive group of equivalent elements** from the range ..." In my case the equivalent elements are spread over the entire collection, therefore you would sort them beforehand if you could.

Comment: how large is the vector?

Comment: The problem with `std::unique` is that it only applies `equivalent` to consecutive elements. Think of the following input: `(a, b, b, a)` -> `(a, b, a)`

Comment: Anyone commenting that `std::unique` doesn't need sorting. For OPs purpose it does. Something like `aabbccaa` will become `abca`, not `abc`, but the latter is what OP needs.

Comment: @Elrond1337 yup its correct, I misunderstood, you would need to sort for them to be consecutive.

Comment: @RichardHodges This is not about performance. My implementation is `O(n^2)` which is ok and actually needed given the specifications. My vector is very small so worse runtimes would be acceptable.

Comment: FYI, an equivalence relation is transitive, to wit, `equiv(a,b)&&equiv(b,c)` implies `equiv(a,c)`.

Comment: @JiveDadson Thanks. It is indeed transitive in my case.

Comment: @Elrond1337 Your example in the comments below is __not__ transitive

Comment: Oh sorry, thats right. My example was bad. A assure you that in my real problem (which is too complicated to describe here, it is). So let's assume that it is indeed an equivalence relation.

Comment: _"Too complicated to describe here"_ Sorry, but that smells.

Comment: Why should the algorithm depend on the details of my equivalence relation? All I'm asking is that the algorithm works for a type which is not comparable with `operator<` but is with `equivalent` or `operator==` which is an equivalence relation. If I'm wrong and it is not an equivalence relation, than the code is broken but this is not your problem.

Comment: You should probably have an comparer compatible with your equivalence function, then `std::sort` + `std::unique` does the job.

Comment: @Jarod42 Depends... I like your approach, but if use case requires that order of elements (those remaining) is retained, sorting might break it...

Comment: @Aconcagua: You might still add an extra index to reorder afterward.

Comment: @Aconcagua: `O(2 * n log(n))` is still `O(n log n)` and from complexity, we gain for any n.

Comment: @Jarod42 I never wrote `O(2n log(n))`... Was referring to the constant `n0` *such that for any `n` > `n0` [...]*. Never mind, let's forget about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since performance is not an issue, you can use `std::accumulate` to scan through the elements and add them to an accumulator vector `xs` if there is not already 
 an equaivalent element in  `xs`.

With this you don't need any hand-written raw loops at all.

```
std::vector<A> filter_all_but_one_for_each_set_of_equivalent_A(std::vector<A> as) {       
    return std::accumulate(as.begin(), as.end(), 
                           std::vector<A>{}, [](std::vector<A> xs, A const& x) {
                               if ( std::find_if(xs.begin(), xs.end(), [x](A const& y) {return equivalent(x,y);}) == xs.end() ) {
                                   xs.push_back(x);
                               }

                               return xs;
                           });
}
```

With two helper functions this becomes actually readable:

```
bool contains_equivalent(std::vector<A> const& xs, A const& x) {
    return std::find_if(xs.begin(), xs.end(), 
                        [x](A const& y) {return equivalent(x,y);}) != xs.end();
};

std::vector<A> push_back_if(std::vector<A> xs, A const& x) {
        if ( !contains_equivalent(xs, x) ) {
            xs.push_back(x);
        }

        return xs;
    };
```

The function itself is just a call to `std::accumulate`:

```
std::vector<A> filter_all_but_one_for_each_set_of_equivalent_A(std::vector<A> as) {       
    return std::accumulate(as.begin(), as.end(), std::vector<A>{}, push_back_if);
}
```

[I've modified AndyG's example code with my proposed function.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aRnHWu0OPeGpRvb7)

As defined above, `std::accumulate` calls `push_back_if` with a copy of the accumulator variable, and the return value is move-assigned to the accumulator again. This is very inefficient, but can be optimized by changing `push_back_if` to take a reference so that the vector is modified in-place. The initial value needs to be passed as a reference wrapper with `std::ref` to eliminate remaining copies.

```
std::vector<A>& push_back_if(std::vector<A>& xs, A const& x) {
        if ( !contains_equivalent(xs, x) ) {
            xs.push_back(x);
        }

        return xs;
    };

std::vector<A> filter_all_but_one_for_each_set_of_equivalent_A(std::vector<A> const& as) {       
    std::vector<A> acc;
    return std::accumulate(as.begin(), as.end(), std::ref(acc), push_back_if);
}
```

[You can see in the example that the copy-constructor is almost completely eliminated.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vt6QHIG37iY9Wh04)

Comment: I can change push_back_if to accept xs by reference and return a reference, and pass the accumulator as a `std::ref(a)` to a local object `a`. That should get rid of almost all copies. It compiles and prints the correct results (https://wandbox.org/permlink/vt6QHIG37iY9Wh04), and I think it should be compliant with the definition of accumulate. There are not many restrictions on the function passed. But the OP specifically said he does not care about performance and wanted a version without hand-written loops, so the accumulate version should meet the requirements.

Comment: @RichardHodges `std::accumulate` should also be implemented as `acc = binary_op(std::move(acc), *i)`, so the vector´s contents should be moved instead of copied all the time. Both libstdc++ and clang do implement accumulate as `__init = __binary_op(__init, *__first);`, so I am guess this is a quality of implementation issue?

Comment: I think it's just that std::accumulate was designed with numeric types in mind. In reality it should probably be revisited to handle complex types efficiently. In this case should probably also be moved to <algorithm>

Comment: @RichardHodges The change to `accumulate` is very recent and not in the C++17 standard. This explains why the standard libraries do not implement it yet.

Comment: See https://wg21.link/p0616R0 for the proposed changes to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment in AndyG's answer:

```
template<class T, class A, class Equivalent>
auto deduplicated2(std::vector<T, A> vec, Equivalent&& equivalent) -> std::vector<T, A>
{
    auto current = std::begin(vec);

    // current 'last of retained sequence'
    auto last = std::end(vec);

    while (current != last)
    {
        // define a predicate which checks for equivalence to current
        auto same = [&](T const& x) -> bool
        {
            return equivalent(*current, x);
        };

        // move non-equivalent items to end of sequence
        // return new 'end of valid sequence'
        last = std::remove_if(std::next(current), last, same);
    }
    // erase all items beyond the 'end of valid sequence'
    vec.erase(last, std::end(vec));
    return vec;
}
```

Credit to AndyG please.

For very large vectors where T is hashable, we can aim for an O(n) solution:

```
template<class T, class A, class Equivalent>
auto deduplicated(std::vector<T, A> const& vec, Equivalent&& equivalent) -> std::vector<T, A>
{
    auto seen = std::unordered_set<T, std::hash<T>, Equivalent>(vec.size(), std::hash<T>(), std::forward<Equivalent>(equivalent));

    auto result = std::vector<T, A>();
    result.resize(vec.size());

    auto current = std::begin(vec);
    while (current != std::end(vec))
    {
        if (seen.insert(*current).second)
        {
            result.push_back(*current);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, revisiting the first solution and refactoring into sub-concerns (I can't help myself):

```
// in-place de-duplication of sequence, similar interface to remove_if
template<class Iter, class Equivalent>
Iter inplace_deduplicate_sequence(Iter first, Iter last, Equivalent&& equivalent)
{
    while (first != last)
    {
        // define a predicate which checks for equivalence to current
        using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
        auto same = [&](value_type const& x) -> bool
        {
            return equivalent(*first, x);
        };

        // move non-equivalent items to end of sequence
        // return new 'end of valid sequence'
        last = std::remove_if(std::next(first), last, same);
    }
    return last;
}

// in-place de-duplication on while vector, including container truncation    
template<class T, class A, class Equivalent>
void inplace_deduplicate(std::vector<T, A>& vec, Equivalent&& equivalent)
{
    vec.erase(inplace_deduplicate_sequence(vec.begin(), 
                                           vec.end(), 
                                           std::forward<Equivalent>(equivalent)), 
              vec.end());
}

// non-destructive version   
template<class T, class A, class Equivalent>
auto deduplicated2(std::vector<T, A> vec, Equivalent&& equivalent) -> std::vector<T, A>
{
    inplace_deduplicate(vec, std::forward<Equivalent>(equivalent));
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Great use of `std::next`

Comment: *"move to end of sequence"* is [not precise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove): *"Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values (as per MoveAssignable post-condition)."* Apart from this small detail, nice answer...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that only has one very simple loop:

First define our class, which I'll call `A` instead of `T` because `T` is typically used for templates:

```
class A{
public:
    explicit A(int _i) : i(_i){};
    int get() const{return i;}
private:
    int i;
};
```

And then our `equivalent` function just compares the integers for equality:

```
bool equivalent(A const& a, A const& b){return a.get() == b.get();}
```

next I'll define the filtering function.

The idea here is to take advantage of [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to do the looping and erasing efficiently for us (it typically swaps elements to the end so that you are not shifting the vector for each removal).

We start by removing everything that matches the first element, then afterwards remove everything that matches the second element (which is guaranteed != to the first element now), and so on.

```
std::vector<A> filter_all_but_one_for_each_set_of_equivalent_A(std::vector<A> as) {
    for(size_t i = 1; i < as.size(); ++i){
       as.erase(std::remove_if(as.begin() + i, as.end(), [&as, i](const A& next){return equivalent(as[i-1], next);}), as.end());
    }
    return as;
}
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IbwgfSWuxML601IQ)

---

Edit: As Richard Hodges mentioned, it is possible to delay any erasing until the very end. I couldn't make it look as beautiful though:

```
std::vector<A> filter_all_but_one_for_each_set_of_equivalent_A(std::vector<A> as) {
    auto end = as.end();
    for(size_t i = 1; i < std::distance(as.begin(), end); ++i){
       end = std::remove_if(as.begin() + i, end, [&as, i](const A& next){return equivalent(as[i-1], next);});
    }
    as.erase(end, as.end());
    return as;
}
```

[Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XEf1DDLmUlaCZbBF)

Comment: nice. +1. I think you could defer the actual erase until the end

Comment: That's certainly better than my solution.

Comment: @RichardHodges Good point. Edited. I just couldn't think of a way to make it look nicer!

Comment: @AndyG posted an answer with a suggestion of how I'd approach it. I think it's more idiomatic (and beautiful) to write it in terms of iterators.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. The trick here is to obtain the index while inside predicate.

```
std::vector<T> output; 
std::copy_if(
    input.begin(), input.end(),
    std::back_inserter(output),
    [&](const T& x) {
        size_t index = &x - &input[0];
        return find_if(
            input.begin(), input.begin() + index, x,
            [&x](const T& y) {
                return equivalent(x, y);
            }) == input.begin() + index;
    });
```

Comment: You'll have to use `std::find_if` instead, though, as elements shall be filtered according to the result of `equivalent` function; alternatively, some `operator==` overload for T is required calling this function. The latter might conflict, though, with an existing overload or prevent providing such one (with different semantics than `equivalent`) later.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks, just edit my answer. I thought `operator==` and `equivalent` can be the same at first.

Comment: To be honest, my own answer evolved exactly the same way... I even left `operator==` there, however, not *implicitly* used. With *explicit* usage necessities for changes are obvious (I assume so at least)...

Answer (score 1):

First coming up with another *loop* version, in contrast to your own, it unifies *in place*, you might find it interesting:

```
std::vector<int> v({1, 7, 1, 8, 9, 8, 9, 1, 1, 7});

auto retained = v.begin();
for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
{
    bool isFirst = true;
    for(auto j = v.begin(); j != retained; ++j)
    {
        if(*i == *j)
        {
            isFirst = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isFirst)
    {
        *retained++ = *i;
    }
}
v.erase(retained, v.end());
```

This was the base for a version using `std::remove_if` and `std::find_if`:

```
auto retained = v.begin();
auto c = [&v, &retained](int n)
        {
            if(std::find_if(v.begin(), retained, [n](int m) { return m == n; }) != retained)
                return true;
            // element remains, so we need to increase!!!
            ++retained;
            return false;
        };
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), c), v.end());
```

You need the lambda in this case, as we need a unique-predicate, whereas equivalent (in my int example represented by `operator==`) is a binary one...

Answer (score 0):

```
struct S {
    int eq;
    int value;
    bool operator==(const S& other) const { return eq == other.eq; }
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<S>
    {
        size_t operator()(const S &s) const
        {
            return hash<int>()(s.eq);
        }
    };
}

array<S, 6> as{ { {1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{ 1,1 },{ 2,1 },{ 3,1 } } };
unordered_set<S> us(as.cbegin(), as.cend());
```

Comment: Which hash function do you use for `unordered_set`? The constant function `hash(t) == 0` would probably work. Interesting.

Comment: Why explicit asiignment operator in `S` which is missing `return`?

Comment: This works for your type `S` which is just two `int`s. For the purpose of the argument lets say my type is an `std::string` and `equivalent` returns true if both strings contain the same word. E.g. "my first string" and "not the first string" would be equivalent, because they both contain the word "first" (word = substring at beginning or end or separated by spaces). Then your hash function needs to map both strings to the same value.

Comment: I down-voted when the answer was two unintelligible lines of code.

Comment: @Elrond1337 That will then not be a equivalence relation and you'll have to redefine what you mean by "unique"